# Doctrine Mongo update $pull query not working

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm attempting to remove references to a document (for the purpose of removing said document) using a `$pull` update query however nothing appears to be happening.

I can manually run the following Mongo query

```
db.collection.update({}, {
    $pull: {
        'field': {'$id': ObjectId("xxxxxxxx")}
    }
}, false, true)
```

which works fine. Attempting to do the same in Doctrine's ODM yields neither the expected result or any error messages. Here's what we have so far

```
$id = new MongoId("xxxxxxxx");

$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->update();
$qb->field('field')->pull(array('$id' => $id));
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Any hints about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, finally found it after trawling through the Doctrine code...

Have to pass the `multi` option through to [`MongoCollection::update()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php)

```
$qb->getQuery(array('multiple' => true))->execute();
```

Comment: I guess you can also use updateMany() instead of update()

Answer (score -3):

```
 $friend = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine')->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder('App\document\Message')->update()->field('unread')->set(TRUE)->field('viewer_id')->equals(10001)-> getQuery(array('multiple' => true))->execute();
```